# Удаление точки в конце заголовка

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, поддержка, предложение

Почему на сайте стаковерфлоу в заголовке темы удаляют последнюю точку?

Господа админы, не надо изобретать свои правила русского языка. В русском языке ставится точка в конце предложения, в том числе и в заголовке. Кроме того, заголовок может состоять из нескольких предложений, каждое из которых отделяется от другого точкой.

Answer (score 18):

В современном русском языке простановка точки в конце заголовков не рекомендуется:

- [Справочная книга редактора и корректора. Составление и общая редакция А. Э. Мильчина. Изд. 2-е, М.: Книга, 1985.](http://www.az-print.com/FAQ/HelpBook/h001.shtml)
- [грамота.ру - Точка в заглавии](http://gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/rr/28_563)

> Точка в заглавии
>   19.12.2006
>
> Б. С. Шварцкопф
>
> В современной русской печати **в конце заголовка употребление точки не принято**. Это положение узаконено специальными пособиями и справочниками для корректоров и редакторов; сошлемся хотя бы на последний такой по времени: «Точку в рубрике (заголовке. – Б. Ш.), вынесенной в отдельную строку, опускают, за исключением изданий для начинающих читать детей (напр., в букваре), чтобы не мешать закреплению стереотипа, в конце предложения надо ставить точку...
>
> **Остальные [написано рукой автора: конечные] знаки препинания (многоточие, восклицательный, вопросительный знаки) сохраняют**» (Справочная книга редактора и корректора. Составление и общая редакция А. Э. Мильчина. Изд. 2-е, М.: Книга, 1985. С. 24). Ср.:

Comment: А если заглавие состоит из нескольких предложений? Как тогда отделять одно предложение от другого? И почему точку из заглавия удаляют, а знак вопроса не удаляют?

Comment: С вопросами "Почему" лучше обратиться в более [профильное коммьюнити](https://rus.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Почему точку удаляют это вопрос к админам а не к филологам. Филологи точек не удаляют. Еще раз - заголовок вопроса может состоять из нескольких предложений, которые должны отделяться точками. В том числе и после последнего предложения в заголовке должна стоять точка.

Comment: @pepsicoca1,`заголовок вопроса может состоять из нескольких предложений, которые должны отделяться точками` — всё правильно. Удаляется только последняя точка, остальные остаются на месте. Пример: «[PAM модуль. Пользователь ввел неверный пароль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/843203/208074)».

Comment: @pepsicoca1 еще раз: отсутствие точки в конце - языковая норма, независимо от вашего желания!

Comment: @pepsicoca1, а точку в конце заголовка не ставят потому, что это не предложение.

Comment: @Arhad а вот это очень странное утверждение...

Comment: @pepsicoca1, к слову, [опускать точки в заголовках начали ещё в 30-х годах прошлого века](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/417787/186102): «„Так как в наших газетах принято давать заголовки без заключительных точек, корректор должен позаботиться о том, чтобы случайно набранные точки были удалены уже в первой корректуре“ (Технико-орфографический словарь-справочник. Под ред. Н. Филиппова. Л., 1933. С. 20)».

Comment: @PavelMayorov, уточню: это не рядовое предложение текста. Как вы отличите заголовок от простого предложения, набранного на отдельной строке (и необязательно это будет абзац) жирным начертанием или вообще крупным кеглем?

Comment: @Arhad да, вот так правильнее. А про отличие не понял: предложение, набранное крупным кеглем да еще и на отдельной строке и с жирным начертанием - это и есть заголовок :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, не всегда. Вот пример, передающий идею: «[Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming. It’s Time for That to Change](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/)». Не думаю что, например, *«Let’s start with the painful truth:»* (двоеточие) или  *«We still <3 and are proud of what we’ve done together.»* (точка) являются заголовками. И нет, то, что я в своём переводе сделал все эти конструкции заголовками, — исключительно моя переработка текста из-за нелюбви к подобному форматированию.

Comment: @Arhad Ну да, по смыслу это не заголовки. А вот по оформлению - заголовки... И да, отличать заголовок от не-заголовка по наличию точки в конце - очень странная идея.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 кстати, «филологи» тоже удаляют точки в конце заголовка :)